# Как изменить таблицу css

Tags: css

Нужно добавить к имени ещё и отчество, но добавляется не в строку, а с абзацем (на рисунке №3). Насколько понимаю, мешает таблица (№1), потому как в Dreamweaver она подсвечивается красным, также как вторая (№2). Как убрать таблицу №1, чтобы отчество добавило в строку?
 И ещё при наведении на Карта сайта и Домой цвет меняется на синий, а на остальных остаётся как и есть (чёрный). И при переходе на закладку например Домой она горит синим, а на остальных нет. Я так понимаю в style.css меняется, только не найду где.

[image: Free image hosting and photo sharing]

[image: хостинг фотоальбомов]

Comment: Нужно видеть ваш хтмл и цсс. Никто не знает, где в вашем стайл.цсс находится код этих блоков. Можете выбрать нужный блок файрбагом и посмотреть на какой линии в файле нужный код?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь **Developers Tools** в Chrome или **FireBug** в Firefox и всё станет намного понятней. Сразу увидите, каким элементам html назначены определённые стили и где они находятся.

Используя эти инструменты Вы можете на ходу корректировать стили и сразу видеть, что изменяется. А уже потом вносить изменения в исходники.

Очень удобно!

Comment: Сейчас выложу css html и попробую ваш совет

Comment: http://narod.ru/disk/27502098001/General%20Site.zip.html

Comment: FireBug вещь удобная, но всё равно не вижу. Или я наверное, что-то не так делаю?

Comment: В FireBug выбираете элемент в структуре вашего документа и смотрите на значения стилей. 

Возможно там таблица общая для 1 и 2 указанных на рисунке, тогда, вероятно, значения width прописаны как атрибуты table.

Comment: Когда я выбираю текст в таблице который мне нужно удалить, то в стилях (Вкладка в окошке справа) я не вижу. Таблицы разные, потому как в Dreamweaver они подсвечиваюстя красной рамкой в определённом месте